# Example using Jersey (REST resource), OSGi (Apache Felix), and Maven (build and deploy)?

Tags: maven, jersey, osgi

I seem to be really struggling here.  What I want to do (in this order) is:

1) Build a RESTful resource using a Jersey application and resource w/annotations (this is not the issue).

2) Package, install, and start that bundle into the Felix OSGi container, as an HTTP service, including dependencies.

3) Package, install, and start a WAR in the OSGi container that may incorporate #2 as a dependency.

And I would like to be able to do all of this using Maven.

I cannot seem to find a working example of even the individual steps, especially involving Maven, that work let alone the combination of those steps. I have tried cobbling together various q&a from across the web with varying levels of success but not an end-to-end working example yet.

Any pointers would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an example for Jersey but I have a [tutorial for CXF with Apache Karaf](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/EoBk) (which uses Felix). It shows how to create a Rest service and build it with maven. Using Apache Karaf you can then deploy the bundle directly from the maven repo. Moving this to Jersey probably just means to exchange the lib and use another blueprint config to initialize the rest service.

Apache Karaf also allows to deploy wars and wabs but I have not yet tested them.

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Stanbol](http://stanbol.apache.org/) does most or all of this (not sure if the war packaging is included out of the box) to implement its RESTful services.

You'll have to dig through its [codebase](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/trunk) but searching for Jax-RS annotations in there should point you to the right places.

Comment: This is helpful but I was hoping for something more straight-forward.  The problem I am having seems to be with my cobbling of everything together from various sources.

I will see what I can come up using Stanbol this week.

Answer (score 1):

I also am really struggling with exactly what you are attempting to do.  So far, I seem to be really close but alas not quite there, here's what I've been doing:

1. creating a War with Maven that defines my Jersey Resource's
2. bundling it with maven bundle plugin ( see section [Adding OSGi metadata to existing projects without changing the packaging type](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) ).  Which allows me to run the restlets in Tomcat and test.
3. define a target in Eclipse that includes resources from my locally defined p2 site which I create with the p2-maven-plugin plugin. In this way I can gather up any of the dependencies from the WAR project into a p2 site, which I can deploy to an Eclipse defined target
4. Where I am stuck is trying to register the Jersey Resource's as services, for which I've tried:
5. using the [JAX-RS OSGI connector](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/01/23/an-osgi-jax-rs-connector-part-1-publishing-rest-services/), for which I eventually gave up on because it uses glassfish jersey which seems to export a version 2 API of Jersey when Jersey hasn't even defined a version 2 API yet.  This caused package resolution problems when I wanted to use version 1.17 of Jersey libs.
6. registering the Resources using a Whiteboard a la [Apache Felix HTTP Service](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html), my current approach which doesn't seem to work yet.
7. And, finally, if the preceding doesn't work I'll try [Amdatu](http://amdatu.org/howto/createwebapp.html)
8. Another route I might try is from the [Jersey project OSGI chapter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#osgi)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this combination and made it up and running -

1-  Modularity Specification-->OSGi specification

2-  OSGi implementation-->Apache Felix 4.4.0

3-  OSGi Runtime-->Apache Karaf 3.0.3

4-  Software Architecture Specification of REST – JAX-RS

5-  JAX-RX implementation-->Apache CXF – 2.7.5

You can refer this nice tutorial - http://java.dzone.com/articles/building-cxf-rest-service-osgi

Now, I am also planning to move to Jersey from CXF as the Jersey is the light wait reference implementation of JAX-RS. Now I am planning to use Jersey with Apache Felix/Apache Karaf. You can install Jersey in Karaf and deploy your Jersey Rest Web Services as Bundle. You can refer this tutorial - https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/web-applications-with-osgi-working-with-jersey/

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example on github : https://github.com/ddragosd/jax-rs-on-karaf

Comment: This looks promising as well.